# Eclipse - Problem Markers from external Tools Console Output

Tags: eclipse, parsing, compilation, console, markers

I am editing source files remotly, using RSE SSH. When I am done the source file need to compiled directly on the server. For this case I wrote an "external tools configuration", which uses Putty (plink.exe) to make an SSH login to the server. I am executing the compiler. Every output is Shown in the console tab in eclipse.

Is there any option or argument or what ever, to grap this output, parse it and create problem markers?

In case the compile isn't able to compile the source file, I will get an output on the console like:  Error number, some text, linenumber. But it is just text and there is no reference to the source file.

I want the user just need to click on the problem marker in the problem tab and directly jumping to the file and line which causes the problem.

Thank you and Best regards.